# Disable multiple GUI controls on button click

Tags: wpf

I bind DelegateCommands to buttons in the UI.
And I am not using Prism.
Now I want to disable/hide certain controls on the UI when a button is clicked.

Do I have to put the Disable/Hide logic into the execute handler of the DelegateCommand itself?
Special focus here: background Worker thread.

```
  this.MyCommand = new DelegateCommand(MyExecutehandler);

    void MyExecutehandler(object obj){
    // 1.) disable controls here
    // 2.) long running operation on background worker here
    // 3.) enable the controls again in the worker_completed handler?
    }
```

The controls would then be disabled/enabled through MVVM.

Comment: A suggestion. Try `async await` instead of BG worker. And I don't find anything wrong in writing the disable logic in execute handler of delegate command.

Comment: Hm, yes if It's pure MVVM this should also work, because I will not have the Dispatcher available  in pure MVVM.

Comment: That's a misconception. You can have `Dispatcher` in pure MVVM too. :)

Comment: Yeah, just saw it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> Special focus here: background Worker thread

So i just make an assumption that you are asking how to modify UI control state from another thread.

Normally we use way below to modify UI thread's control from worker thread

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( <your delegate here>)
```

But i suspect that you can't do that in background worker thread as 'this' will mostly differ. So you may try this :

```
button.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>
{
 //disable button here
}));
```

It is like worker thread send a message to tell UI thread to run the delegate.

One more thing, normally we disabled a control and re-enable a button after some process to avoid some unnecessary attached event/propertychanged event. So I suspect you may need this:

You can done that by removing event temporarily:

```
 button -= button_click_event
```

and Re-add event after that

```
 button += button_click_event
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind visibility property of controls which you want to disable and in MyExecutehandler function set property values to visibility.collapse

Comment: This was not asked. But your approach would create a dependency to the UI framework... so bool is the way to go in conjunction with a converter